# How to start Mobile Broadband connection in openSUSE?

Tags: opensuse, internet, modem, 3g

I have openSUSE Tumbleweed installed on my x64 laptop, with the latest updates (at least almost...) I managed to create a Mobile Broadband Network Connection for my Alcatel One Touch modem, with a data SIM-card, but I haven't found a way to start it. A red light keeps flashing on the modem. (It worked when connected to a Windows machine.)

Can someone tell me how to connect to the internet through this modem?
(Please let me know if you need more information, and I will add that to this question. I would know what else is needed if I knew the answer...)

#### UPDATE #1:

The information commenters asked from me:

1. "Plug in the USB modem , run lsusb , just give the codes of the USB : ID"

   ```
   Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0461:4d0f Primax Electronics, Ltd HP Optical Mouse
   Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1bbb:f000 T & A Mobile Phones 
   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6409 Microdia Webcam
   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   ```
2. "Is the modem detected?"

   I would say yes, but I am not sure.

   - First, the output of `dmesg` contains this: `usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected`. I have no other USB device connected, so I would think this is the one.
   - Second, `udevadm` displays quite a few events when I plug in or unplug the device.
   - But the Modem Manager GUI does not list any modems.
3. "Are the drivers installed and loaded?"

   I didn't install any, and not sure if it is installed, or loaded. How do you check that? I also haven't found an installer for download.
4. "What type of connection is used? PPPoE?"

   How can you tell? The Network Connections dialog where I configured the connection doesn't say that.

I also applied as many as I could of the suggestions of the following pages, but to no avail:

- [How to use Alcatel One Touch X220L 3G modem in Linux](http://linuxtricksandtips.blogspot.hu/2010/12/how-to-use-alcatel-one-touch-x220l-3g.html)
- [How to install Alcatel's One Touch (l100) 4G modem in a Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462994/how-to-install-alcatels-one-touch-l100-4g-modem-in-a-ubuntu-14-04)

#### UPDATE #2:

I added the following to `/etc/usb_modeswitch.conf`:

```
########################################################
# Alcatel X220L

DefaultVendor=  0x1bbb
DefaultProduct= 0xf000

TargetVendor=   0x1bbb
TargetProduct=  0x0000

# only for reference
# MessageEndpoint=0x01

MessageContent="55534243123456788000000080000606f50402527000000000000000000000"
########################################################
```

Then I exectuted `usb_modeswitch` for this configuration file:

```
usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf
```

The output I got:

```
Look for target devices ...
 No devices in target mode or class found
Look for default devices ...
   product ID matched
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 014 on bus 002
Get the current device configuration ...
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
Use endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: USBModem
     Product: Mobile Broad Band
  Serial No.: not provided
-------------------------
Looking for active driver ...
 OK, driver detached
Set up interface 0
Use endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 1 (CSW) ...
 Response reading failed (error -8)
 Device is gone, skip any further commands
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!
```

When I run it again, this is what I get:

```
Look for target devices ...
 No devices in target mode or class found
Look for default devices ...
 No devices in default mode found. Nothing to do. Bye!
```

If I remove and plug the device in again, then I again get the long output.

#### UPDATE #3:

Following advice from a commenter, I compared the outputs from lsusb before and after trying what is suggested [here](http://pastebin.com/yV4Dezi8). The following line appeared:

```
Bus 002 Device 020: ID 1bbb:f000 T & A Mobile Phones
```

Note that it contains `1bbb:f000`, whereas I think the "f000" should have been replaced by "0017" (or the "0000" used in what I tried earlier) after running `usb_modeswitch`. I do not yet know what the reason is.

Comment: Did you get usb_modeswitch running? Can you post it's debug output?

Comment: @maxf Sure, please see my 2nd update. Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: Please try [this](http://pastebin.com/yV4Dezi8) in your usb_modeswitch.conf and post lsusb after executing usb_modeswitch.